# Driver trouble with my BCM4331 on my Macbook Pro 9 2

Tags: wireless, drivers, broadcom, macbook

I've finally gotten my wifi working on my Macbook Pro 9 2 (Fully booted with Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit) ,but it is only working on the Broadcom STA/WL driver that comes with this version of Ubuntu. I've been all over the forums on the web and I've gathered that this driver doesn't support Monitor Mode, but the b43 driver that is already installed on my computer does.

```
03:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4331 802.11a/b/g/n (rev 02)
```

I've tried:

```
rmmod -r wl
rmmod -r b43
modprobe b43
```

and also tried blacklisting the `wl` driver. All it does is completely ignores the fact that I can use wireless. No "firmware missing" or anything like that. It's just not there. I know that b43 supports the bcm4331 card I have, but it isn't.

This is all the information I can think to give, but of course if I have left anything useful out just tell me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i suggest you the first thing I done with my wifi card `rfkill unblock all`

or try to compile the last stable kernel on your hardware (worked for me with 10.04)

Comment: I tried the rfkill and it didn't change anything. I tried rmmod wl and modprobe b43 afterwards and I restarted, but wl was running when I rebooted. Thanks for your help man, I've been trying to get this thing working for hours.

Comment: how about the new kernel Full source?